# Python: Desired and Undesired Duplicates - Removing duplicates ONLY IF they come from different files. Keep duplicates that come from the same file

Tags: python

I am merging several transaction files, and sometimes there are overlaps across time periods, meaning I have **undesired repeat transactions**.

There are also **desired repeat transactions**, which are transactions that are made on the same day for the same amount and with the same description.

How can I modify the code below to keep DESIRED (same file, real duplicate transactions) and remove UNDESIRED (overlap across files, fake duplicate transactions) repeat transactions?

I have outlined below the Steps 1-3 that I am thinking of writing code for. If you have a smarter structure, please feel free to modify, still a beginner here :-)

```
# Create dataframe with all previous data files

df_list = []

for f in files:
    # Extract the file name without the extension
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]
    
    # Read the CSV file and add the file_name as a new column
    df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf-8', dtype=str,
                     names=['Date', 'Description', 'Amount', 'Category'],
                     low_memory=True)
    df['file_name'] = file_name
    
    df_list.append(df)

# Create dataframe:
df = pd.concat(df_list)

df

# Step 1: Create a mask for duplicates based on transaction data
duplicates = df.duplicated(subset=['Date', 'Description', 'Amount', 'Category'], keep=False)

# Step 2: Remove DESIRED duplicates (same file) from the duplicates df

# Step 3: Drop only the remaining duplicates (across files) and keep the latest file's DESIRED duplicates 
(e.g. if there is an overlap between files that contain desired duplicate transactions, only keep the latest one)
```